# eclipse warning A compatible JRE is available but has been overridden

Tags: java, eclipse

I've just updated my projects to java 8, and eclipse is giving this WARNING for each and every project in the workspace:

Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.8. A compatible JRE is available but has been overridden.
Warning Location: Build path
Warning Type: JRE System Library Problem

eclipse.ini is set to java 8 vm: java8/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
I removed JAVA_HOME variable from the system environment (which pointed to java 7) but for no avail.

Forgot to mention: using m2e maven eclipse plugin.

Tried to search eclipse sources to see what is causing this warning, but couldn't find my arms and legs.
Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Finally found that for some reason, eclipse thought JavaSE-1.8 for java 7.
The configuration that solved the problem:
Preferences ->Java -> Installed JREs -> Execution Environments
Select "JavaSE-1.8" from left list and check "java8 [perfect match]" in the right list.